# How to access created artifacts in groovy script for a particular build

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a stage in my groovy script that produces two json files using the `getImageVulnsFromQualys` function (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/qualys-cs/)
When the script finishes, I get two json files with random hashes as their filenames for artifacts. I cannot statically reference each file to parse since the names of the json files will be random each time the build finishes. I want to be able to read the two json files and parse through the file in the same stage or in another stage in the same script. I was hoping Groovy would have a simple function that allows me to retrieve all artifacts for a particular build and I could parse each artifact. What is the best way for me to retrieve all these artifacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something similiar to find the artifact names. Here is an example for a var step to find the files and then their content:

```
//getArtifactToConentMap.groovy 

def call(args) {
    def build = args.build
    def regex = args.regex
    def files = build.getArtifacts()
    Map<String, String> artifactNameToContent = [:]
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
        def f = files[i]
        if (f.name ==~ regex) {
            String artifactName = f.relativePath
            String artifactVirtualFile = build.getArtifactManager().root().child(artifactName)
            String artifactContent = getVirtualFileConent(artifactVirtualFile)
            artifactNameToContent.put(artifactName, artifactContent)

        }
    }
    return artifactNameToContent
}

def getVirtualFileConent(def virtualFile){
    InputStream is = null
    try {
        is = a.open()
        return is.text
    } finally {
        is?.close()
    }
}
```

Then you can use as follows:

```
Map<String, String> jsonArtifactsNameToContent = getArtifactToConentMap(build: currentBuild.rawBuild, regex: /.*\.json/))
```